# How do I create a custom ispell affix file to stub -isms and -ists?

Tags: ispell

I want to create an ispell stubber such that,

```
echo communism | ispell -c
echo communist | ispell -c
echo communists | ispell -c
```

All return the same thing. I'm making a website based on ideology, and I'm trying to create a more intelligent tagging system.

Comment: As a starting point, there's a [description](http://aspell.net/man-html/Affix-Compression.html) of the aspell affix file format that you find used in `/usr/lib*/aspell*/en_affix.dat`.